# Excel VBA - Copy Table Rows to another worksheet if within date range

Tags: excel, vba

I have an "Outages" worksheet table that I enter information in with a start date and end date. After the information is entered, a "2 Week Look Ahead" button will run a macro to copy any rows that are within the next 2 weeks to the "2 Week Look Ahead" worksheet.

["Outages" worksheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CmoIF.jpg)

The information copies to the "2 Week Look Ahead" sheet, but it duplicates the data on the next row, and shifts it to the left.

["2 Week Look Ahead" worksheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QMZPA.jpg)

I am new to VBA. Can someone help me cleanup my code and fix this problem?

```
Sub Copy_Click()
' Prompt for confirmation before clearing current 2 Week Look Ahead

Dim varResponse As Variant
varResponse = MsgBox("Clear the current 2 Week Lookahead and continue?", vbYesNo, "Selection")
If varResponse <> vbYes Then Exit Sub

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("2 Week Look Ahead").Range("10:1000").Delete xlUp ' Clears 2 Week Look Ahead sheet, rows 10-1000

' Set Variables
Dim startdate As Date, enddate As Date
Dim rng As Range, destRow As Long
Dim shtSrc As Worksheet, shtDest As Worksheet
Dim c As Range '-- this is used to store the single cell in the For Each loop

Set shtSrc = Sheets("Outages") ' Sets "Outages" sheet as source
Set shtDest = Sheets("2 Week Look Ahead") 'Sets "2 Week Look Ahead" as destination

destRow = 10 'Start copying to this row on destination sheet

' Use 2 week date range from this week's start

startdate = CDate(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("2 Week Look Ahead").Range("G7"))  ' Use this week Sunday date for start date
enddate = CDate(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("2 Week Look Ahead").Range("I7")) ' Use 2 weeks from Sunday date for end date

' Set range to search for dates in 2 week period
Set rng = Application.Intersect(shtSrc.Range("C5:D1000"), shtSrc.UsedRange)

'Look for matching dates in columns C5 to D1000
For Each c In rng.Cells
    If c.Value >= startdate And c.Value <= enddate Then ' Does date fall between start and end dates? If Yes, then copy to destination sheet

        c.Offset(0, -2).Resize(1, 12).Copy _
                      shtDest.Cells(destRow, 1) 'Copy a 12 cell wide block to the other sheet, paste into Column A on row destRow

        destRow = destRow + 1

    End If 'Ends search for dates
Next
Sheets("2 Week Look Ahead").Activate ' Changes view to 2 Week Look Ahead Sheet


End Sub
```

Comment: Wouldn't AutoFilter'ing on a date range be more efficient?

Comment: I'm unclear on whether the '2 week' date window applies to column C, column D or (somehow) both.

Comment: Basically, if either the start or end date occurs within the next 2 weeks, that row should be copied to the lookahead worksheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adjust the following,

```
' Set range to search for dates in 2 week period
Set rng = Application.Intersect(shtSrc.Range("C5:D1000"), shtSrc.UsedRange)
```

... to,

```
Set rng = Application.Intersect(shtSrc.Range("C5:C1000"), shtSrc.UsedRange)
```

... and,

```
 ' Does date fall between start and end dates? If Yes, then copy to destination sheet
 If c.Value >= startdate And c.Value <= enddate Then
```

... to,

```
 If (c.Value >= startdate And c.Value <= enddate) Or _
    (c.offset(0, 1).Value >= startdate And c.offset(0, 1).Value <= enddate) Then
```

Comment: @sparkynerd - Mark it as the answer then. Keeps everybody informed and it's especially important as a new user to show responders that you value their suggestions - especially when they've helped you to find the answer.